# scikit-learn PCA differences when specifying n_components

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I have some data `X` that I run PCA on. I'd like to return all of the principal components and then select the first few after inspection, rather than a priori selection. I was just transforming X with scikit-learn's `PCA` and then achieving my selection by simply `X[:, :n_components]` after transforming. However, I noticed something odd in my data. I tried reproducing the problem in a fake example but it runs just fine:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

n_components = 4

X1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, (500, 30))
X2 = X1.copy()

assert np.allclose( X1, X2 )

pca1, pca2 = PCA(), PCA(n_components=n_components)

X1 = pca1.fit_transform(X1)
X2 = pca2.fit_transform(X2)

assert np.allclose(X1[:, :n_components], X2)
```

Using the same process, just with my own data I get the following:

```
X1 = X.copy()
X2 = X.copy()

assert np.allclose(X1, X2)

np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

if configs['pca']['run']:
    pca1 = PCA(**configs['pca']['parameters'])
    pca2 = PCA(random_state=0)
    X1 = pca1.fit_transform(X1)
    X2 = pca2.fit_transform(X2)

print("X1:\n", X1[:3])
print("X2:\n", X2[:3, :configs['pca']['parameters']['n_components']])
    
assert np.allclose(X1, X2[:, :configs['pca']['parameters']['n_components']])
```

The output is:

```
X1:
 [[ 0.37486351 -0.19900685  0.1427147  -0.26709366 -0.15067396  0.01981867]
 [ 0.37461979  0.47905469  0.04657452 -0.08894677  0.27989207 -0.03185509]
 [-0.34283884  0.40882146 -0.05911666 -0.04694395 -0.02077442 -0.14203045]]
X2:
 [[ 0.37486351 -0.19900684  0.14271459 -0.26709352 -0.15067327  0.01981888]
 [ 0.37461979  0.47905469  0.04657449 -0.08894674  0.27989226 -0.03185508]
 [-0.34283884  0.40882146 -0.05911665 -0.04694396 -0.02077448 -0.14203045]]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\L\Documents\Projects\Accelogress\clustering\run\clustering.py", line 141, in <module>
    assert np.allclose(X1, X2[:, :configs['pca']['parameters']['n_components']])

AssertionError
```

It looks to me like this is just rounding error, but I would like to know why this doesn't occur on the practice data?

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps, but the documentation says, "... a randomized truncated SVD by the method of Halko et al. 2009, depending on the shape of the input data and the number of components to extract."

Comment: just by looking the data, it seems they are very close, it could be just numerical issue. why don't you set the random_state of pca1?

Comment: @Reza the `configs['pca']['parameters']` contains a `random_state` equal to 0, should have mentioned that.